# posting JS arrays to ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, post

I have a webpage with an array.

The size of the array is determined by the user. it may be of length 0, infinity, and everything in between.

I use this line to post it to an ASP.Net page

```
$.post("MyPage.aspx", { DataSet: MyArray})
      .done(function (data) {
          alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
          });
```

I tried everything I can think of

```
$.post("MyPage.aspx", { 'DataSet[]': MyArray})
```

but nothing seems to work. the alert always comes up empty. (not even undefined, just "")

What am I doing wrong?

Thank!

Comment: use firebug/fiddler to see whether your POST works with proper data

Answer (score 0):

If I code the following:

```
MyArray = [0, 1, 2];

$.post("MyPage.aspx", { DataSet: MyArray})
    .done(function (data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
```

The data is POSTed as follows:

```
DataSet[]:0
DataSet[]:1
DataSet[]:2
```

So it depends on whether your `MyPage.aspx` is processing the data in this format (you haven't pasted the server code), and what it is returning to the JavaScript to cause "" to be returned.